# Cassandra data model for interval and event based time series

Tags: cassandra, time-series, data-modeling

I have to collect time series data from various IoT sensors. Based on my research there are two different types of time series data streams.

**Case 1 : Fixed interval**

This type of data stream has a fixed interval and its very easy to select data points between a given range. A typical use case would be a **counter**.

[image: Interval based stream]

**Case 2 : Event based**

This type of data stream comes at irregular points in time and only occurs when something is about to change. A typical use case would be a **power switch** when a sensor is going offline or online.

[image: Event based stream]

**Requirements**

Selecting all affected data points between a given time window

**Data model**

This is my cassandra data model. Any point in the stream can be modeled by

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_raw (
  sensor_id    text,
  bucket_id    date,
  sensor_time  timestamp,
  sensor_value  double,
  PRIMARY KEY ((sensor_id, bucket_id), sensor_time )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (sensor_time DESC);
```

**Solution for case 1**

This is very easy and needs no further discussion

```
SELECT * FROM sensor_raw where 
sensor_id = '1' AND
bucket_id = '2017' AND 
sensor_time >= '2017-01-01 10:00' 
AND sensor_time < '2017-01-01 10:14'
```

**Solution for case 2**

Here i have the problem that events from outside the window can overlap into the selected range. For example **E1**

Another problem is the last event **E3** where the event has not yet finished.

**I need**

1. Partial duration from **window start** to **E1**.

   *To get this info i would have to look back from the first event in the   stream to get the previous one. Then calculate the difference from window start to E2.*
2. Duration from **E2** to **E3**

   *This is easy*
3. Duration from **E2** to **window end** ( not yet finished )

   *Would have to check if last event has same timestamp as window end and if not last event is still running.*

**Result**

[image: Wanted result]

**Question**

Is there any better data model for case 2 ?

Is there any way to not have an additional query to get the solution i need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you pretty much covered all the scenarios. One thing that could help you is if you could create an events table where the data with the "event" type and end_time would go. Something on the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_raw_events (
  sensor_id         text,
  bucket_id         date,
  event_end_time    timestamp,
  event_begin_time  timestamp,
  event_type        text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((sensor_id, bucket_id), sensor_end_time )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (sensor_end_time DESC);
```

The prerequisite for that would be that you actually have some sort of layer that would be able to track the events switching on the application level. A project I worked on had to keep sessions when connecting to devices due to protocol requirements so this wasn't really a problem I guess.

We basically had small in memory grid that was keeping the current state of every sensor with periodic flushing to cassandra - this was only for recovering should all the application go down, but this never happened.

This approach would probably require a lot of memory resources for running it so if you are having millions of sensors this might get too expensive and it doesn't add much value so basically it all depends on scale that you actually have.

Plus one down side of the idea is that you wouldn't really catch the event that is currently ongoing because it's not written to the table yet. But would actually be o.k. for analytical workload because you wouldn't have to make additional query to fetch the beginning of the E1, it would already be there for you.

Some approaches with one table with begin_time and end_time might also be possible but then again this just wastes space (and with sensors it get's packed pretty quick).

Your model and how you described it is pretty much very similar to stuff that I did before and with cassandra alone there simply isn't much more that is known to me that you can do :(

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I came up with nearly the same solution. Glad to see some people have the same problems :)